# Cisco ASR1001 licence throughput measurement

Tags: cisco, throughput, cisco-asr

Cisco `ASR1001` comes with 2.5G throughput license and later you can upgrade to 20G. I have question if i have 10G link and i get attack of 5G and i use ACL to drop all packet on ingress interface in that case does 2.5G comes in picture?  How does 2.5G throughput affect my requirement to drop all packet in Ingress.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes those dropped packets would factor into available throughput, and this is because ACLs are processed by the ESP [Embedded Services Processor] which measures bandwidth. All those packets are being processed by the ESP.

Anything beyond the licensed throughput during that point in time will not be processed. This includes both good and malicious traffic.

More information on where the various components are handled on the ASR can be found in the following document:http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/asr-1000-series-aggregation-services-routers/qa_c67-452124.html